# BASH: loop-reading a list creating a dynamic array

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I have a list formatted as below. If I replace the list by, say, "aaa bbb ccc", everything works fine. Anyone an idea?

```
list=$(echo -e "1.1 1.2 mgmt")

n=0
for i in $list; do
   let "array1_$i[$n]=$(date "+%N")"
   ((++n))
done

n=0
for i in $list; do
   var=array1_$i[$n]
   echo ${!var}
   ((++n))
done
```

thanks in advance for any ideas...

Answer (score 1):

You can change the shebang line to

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
```

to see what bash tries to run. In fact, you are trying to create a variable named `array1_1.1`, which is not a valid variable name: dots are not allowed.

Comment: I am amazed at the usefulness of that information. I can *see* what bash tries to run? UPVOTE.  (On investigation, -xv also works for `dash` (my favored shell for scripts that have to run really fast), `zsh`, `ksh` and possibly all other major sh-variants.)

Answer (score 1):

`.` is not a valid character in an identifier.

`man bash`:

```
       name   A word consisting only of alphanumeric characters and underscores, and
              beginning with an alphabetic character or an underscore.  Also
              referred to as an identifier
```